# Excel VBA Calculate Method not update Array Formulas; showing as #N/A

Tags: excel, array-formulas, vba

I have a series of array formulas in Excel that key off of each other. These are automatically resized to fit a range of data that is generated via a proprietary Excel add-in.

However, whenever my code rewrites some of the array formulas to the correct new size, the cells all show as #N/A until either you edit another unrelated cell on the sheet, save the sheet, or press F9.

Using code such as Application.Calculate, ActiveSheet.Calculate, etc do not have any effect.

However, using SendKeys "{F9}" does.

As an example, these are two formulas on the sheet:

```
={IF(LEN(INDEX(A:A, ROW()))>0,ROW(A:A)+2)}
```

and

```
={LARGE(OFFSET($J$1,0,0,ROW()),1)}
```

The first formula works fine after writing it programmatically to a range of cells. It merely tells me the row number of a cell that has text in it.

The second formula does not work after writing it programmatically to a range of cells. It gives me the largest row number that has been previously seen in a list of numbers (which is the output of the first formula). If I press F9, the second formula updates correctly. If I do Application.Calculate in VBA, nothing happens. I've also tried the various other recalculate methods available at the Worksheet level as well, but no luck.

Has anyone encountered something like this before?

**edit:**
The resize code essentially boils down to something like this (stripping out all of the support code that allows me to make more generalized calls to it):

First, I do:

```
formula = dataSheet.Cells(startRow, startColumn).formula
```

Then later:

```
Set DeleteRange = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(startRow, startColumn), dataSheet.Cells(bottomBound, rightBound))
DeleteRange.ClearContents
Set DeleteRange = Nothing
```

Then later on:

```
Set resultRange = dataSheet.Range(dataSheet.Cells(startRow, startColumn), dataSheet.Cells(startRow + Height - 1, startColumn + Width - 1))
resultRange.FormulaArray = formula
Set resultRange = Nothing
```

In a nut shell, I make a copy of the formula, clear the range, then rewrite it.

Comment: Can you plst post your full code - seeing the resizing would be useful

Comment: I added the basis of the resize code. It's nothing special; I think there are a hundred and one discussions online about how to automatically resize array formulas online?

Comment: I can duplicate your issue in xl2003, but interestingly it worked fine in xl2010. I tried variants for forcing calculation etc. In the end the only way I could find to force the formula to update by itself immediately was to make it volatile, ie `strFormula = "=LARGE(OFFSET($J$1,0,0,ROW()),1)+ RAND()*0"`. +1 for an interesting question.  Are you working in xl03?

Comment: @brettdj: thanks for info! I am actually using 2007. I thought I read somewhere that OFFSET was supposed to be a volatile function, but I guess not... At any rate, it seems that adding a RAND() in there helps it to update when Calculate is called. I think that is a reasonable workaround for my purposes. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Still having this problem in Excel 2016... Kudos Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fleshed out my comment above given you have implemented this approach

using this code

```
Dim strFormula As String
strFormula = "=LARGE(OFFSET($J$1,0,0,ROW()),1)"
Range("a1:a5").FormulaArray = strFormula
```

- xl03 gives numbers but needs a calc to update the cells properly
- xl07 gives the "#N/A" (and raises a `Calculate` in the statusbar)
- xl10 works fine

As you point out none of the calculation options including a full dependency tree rebuild work

using my `RAND` suggestion above does force the update in xl07

```
Dim strFormula As String
strFormula = "=LARGE(OFFSET($J$1,0,0,ROW()),1)+ RAND()*0"
Range("a1:a5").FormulaArray = strFormula
```

`OFFSET` is a volatile function see [Voltatile Excel Functions](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm) (which includes a file that tests volatility)

Perhaps Charles Williams can shed some light on this, I will ping him

Answer (score 3):

If you can't beat 'em, join 'em.

```
SendKeys "{F9}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a FormulaArray bug in 2003 and 2007.
A simpler bypass for your formula would be to use Range("a1:A5").Formula instead of formula array since =LARGE(OFFSET($J$1,0,0,ROW()),1) does not need to be an array formula

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Charles! I think to stay consistent with the other array formulas I am using, I will try making those formulas volatile for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

My recollection is that there is also an `Application.CalculateFull` method - does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, from what I have tried, none of the `Application.CalculateFull` or `Application.CalculateFullRebuild` work. I even tried marking the Range as Dirty first, but it doesn't seem to work as I would have expected. (It still shows as #N/A unless I hit F9 or make a trivial edit to a cell manually).

Answer (score 0):

My cells were not refreshing after ranges they depended on were modified either.
I also had to hand edit each one to get them to re-calculate.

SOLUTION:

Use fully qualified references within your formulas.
e.g. any formulas that look like this `YourFunction(G200:H700)` should be changed to look like this `YourFunction('Your Sheet Name'!G200:H700)`.

Auto-Refresh now works perfectly for me.